# Rationality of roots of polynomial equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

what's the rationality of the roots of polynomial related to the rationality of its coefficient? Here is the question just came up to me, is that true for a polynomial with irrational coefficient cannot has a rational root. Is any theorem about this?

Comment: **Hint** $\rm\ \pi x\ $ has a rational root.

Answer (score 2):

As another example, the polynomial
$$
x^2 - (\pi +1) x + \pi
$$
has $1$ as a root, and no multiple of it by a nonzero constant has all coefficients rational.

If you want all coefficients to be non-rational, (see comment by @MartinBrandenburg)
$$
\pi x^2 - (\pi^2 +\pi) x + \pi^2
$$
will do.

Comment: This has also a rational coefficient.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, ok, thanks, but multyplying by a constant of course you can make any polynomial monic.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti but if you put it into an equation, its the same as the previous one

Comment: @AndreasCaranti anyway you have already give the answer what i want, thanks

Comment: @DylanZhu, you're welcome!